# Search engine in Expo

Tags: react-native, search, expo, lodash

I follow this [tutorial](https://blog.jscrambler.com/add-a-search-bar-using-hooks-and-flatlist-in-react-native/) to add search to my Expo (React Native) app. After the last step I have this mistake:[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1na0.png).

What should I do?

This is the part of the program.

This is one of my navigation screens, where I have links for other screens:

```
    function InfoScreen({ navigation }) {
      return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
          <Button title="Go back" onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} />
                          <View style={styles.container_new}>
          <Text style={styles.text}>Basic FlatList Example</Text>
          <FlatList
          ListHeaderComponent={renderHeader} 
          ...
                  </View> 
                )}
              /> 
            </View>        
            </View> 
          );
        }
```

Function renderHeader from the tutorial:

```
        function renderHeader() {
      return (
       ...
     );
    }
```

Part from the tutorial (last steps)

```
    const [query, setQuery] = useState('');
    const [fullData, setFullData] = useState([]);


useEffect(() => {
  setIsLoading(true);

  fetch(API_ENDPOINT)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
      setData(response.results);

      // ADD THIS
      setFullData(response.results);

      setIsLoading(false);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      setIsLoading(false);
      setError(err);
    });
}, []);

const handleSearch = text => {
  const formattedQuery = text.toLowerCase();
  const filteredData = filter(fullData, user => {
    return contains(user, formattedQuery);
  });
  setData(filteredData);
  setQuery(text);
};

const contains = ({ name, email }, query) => {
  const { first, last } = name;

  if (first.includes(query) || last.includes(query) || email.includes(query)) {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
};
```

Comment: Are you sure that `Part from the tutorial (last steps)` are inside a functional component ?

Comment: @BelginAndroid yes, function InfoScreen is using as a part of the navigation system (there are also SettingsScreen, SearchScreen).

Answer (score 0):

We would need the full contextual component to see what's really going on in and see where the invalid hook call is.

The most likely culprit is one of your handlers like `handleSearch` is being called during rendering. You aren't sharing your rendering code, so I can't help and identify where that's happening. Could you share more?