# I have two versions of React Native in one app

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, expo

I can't render the app (If you are interested, please, check [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65302112/search-engine-in-expo)). I think, I have problems with React Native versions.

```
npm ls react-dom
```

answer: react-dom@16.13.1

```
npm ls react-native
```

answer: NMET PEER DEPENDENCY react-native@0.63.2
npm ERR! peer dep missing: react-native@^0.49.1, required by react-native-deck-swiper@2.0.5

How to fix this? I can't delete deck-swiper, because it's one of the main function in my app.

Comment: Could you paste the content of your `package.json` file? From the error message I would think that you don't have any version of RN installed...

Comment: @Michael 
    ` "@react-navigation/native": "^5.8.10",    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-39.0.4.tar.gz",
    "react-native-deck-swiper": "^2.0.5",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.1" `